# Как реализовать данный синтаксис? [PHP]

Tags: php

Вроде в ларавеле видел

```
$object = new $class_name

$object->table('table_name')->select(`id`)->where ...
```

как лучше всего реализовать такой подход? а то не получается)

Comment: Синтаксис нельзя реализовать, его можно придерживаться или нет.. А конкретно это вы создаёте экземпляр класса `$class_name` и дальше работаете с `query builder/schema builder`'ом.. Не надо такое реализовывать... Выучите тот же laravel и будет вам профит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возвращать в методах класса объект

```
public function name()
{
    //тело метода
    return $this
}
```

Comment: а другой объект нельзя возвращать?

Comment: `functuion` всё таки исправьте